# how to make a ListBox change the text of an item?

Tags: .net, listbox

I have a .net winforms ListBox and I've added items to it using .Add(). I change one of the objects in the list, such that it's ToString() method now returns a different value, but the display value of the item doesn't update. What do I need to call to tell the ListBox to re-read the ToString values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've added the items by hand, you'll need to clear the list box items, and re-add them.

When you add an item with .ToString(), the list box just has a copy of the string itself - it has no way to know that the item has changed, or that it was even based off an item.  You'll have to handle this yourself.

Answer (score 5):

If you re-assign the same object reference to the same listbox item, the listbox will refresh its display value.  e.g.:

```
Thingy thing = this.listBox1.Items[0];
thing.DoSomethingThatChangesToStringReturnValue();

this.listBox1.Items[0] = thing;
```